# no main manifest attribute error for maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium

i have a project in eclipse where i try to run a selenium junit test.
I converted the project to Maven
When i run this java -jar My-Test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

It says:
no main manifest attribute, in My-Test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

What is wrong with me pom file?

The pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.blogspot.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>My-Test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>My-Test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.44.0</version>
    </dependency>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
          <shadedClassifierName>all</shadedClassifierName>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your project a web project?? Because as I know, Selenium only works with web projects. And there you have your project packaged as a jar (not as a war)

Comment: I know that, but it is your project a web project?

Comment: Yes it is a web project with selenium

Comment: I resolved the problem, i just followed the example of mkyong and replace java code, add the selenium jar and everything was fine, and it is a jar and not war project, thank you